# Como dibujar una linea recta sobre una imagen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de dibujar una linea horizontal sobre una imagen que esta en un `ImageView`, la idea es que pase por el centro de la imagen lo que pasa es que llegado a este public void se me cierra la app.
En que estoy mal o de que otra forma podría hacerlo.

```
public void Linea(){
    BitmapDrawable drawable =(BitmapDrawable)imgviewImagenOriginal.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap= drawable.getBitmap();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
 
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 51));

    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    int startx = bitmap.getWidth()/2;

    int starty = bitmap.getHeight();

    int endx = bitmap.getWidth()/2;

    int endy = 0;

    canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar esto puedes crear una clase personalizada que extienda de ImageView (AppCompatImageView) y dentro de su método onDraw() dibujar la linea recta.

```
package com.jorgesys.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


public class CustomImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {

        public CustomImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            canvas.drawLine(0, this.getHeight()/2, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()/2, p);

        }
}
```

Dentro de tu layout define esta clase definiendo el paquete donde se encuentra

```
<com.jorgesys.views.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    ...
    ... />
```

Carga la imagen dentro de tu `ImageView` personalizado ya sea desde una url, o desde los mismos recursos:

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    imageView .setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
```

al cargar la imagen se dibujara también la línea recta, para obtener como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]